# Issues Rendering ActionText With Rails 7 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, actiontext

I've created a Rails 7 app and have thus far, only configured it to use Bootstrap5.3.2 (Bootstrap appears to be working correctly). I've attempted to install ActionText but the textbox is not displaying. I've gotten ActionText to work in previous versions of Rails.

Here is my app/assets/javascript/application.js file...

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
import * as bootstrap from "./bootstrap"
import * as popper from "./popper"
```

Here is my package.json file...

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^7.1.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.7",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "trix": "^2.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css:compile": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules",
    "build:css:prefix": "postcss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --use=autoprefixer --output=./app/assets/builds/application.css",
    "build:css": "yarn build:css:compile && yarn build:css:prefix",
    "watch:css": "nodemon --watch ./app/assets/stylesheets/ --ext scss --exec \"yarn build:css\"",
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ]
}
```

Here is my config/importmap.rb file...

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "trix"
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.esm.js"
pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true
```

Here are my views/layouts/application.html.erb imports...

```
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "actiontext", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>

    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true, type:"module" %>
```

This is what my action_text box looks like. Under "Description" is where the textbox is supposed to render...

[Link To Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca0Yq.png)

What have I tried so far? I've tried modifying my imports, adding the "type:module" to the package.json file, and reinstalling my package.json file to no avail.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about Bootstrap, but if it is you should tag your version. Otherwise remove the tag.